# Rails embeded html img tag inside of a erb link_to tag

Tags: html, erb

Trying to do something like this

```
<%= link_to "<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<%= clip.adress %>/0.jpg"
 height="196" width="110"></img>".html_safe, "#" %>
```

Not sure if I need to mention it but there is also erb inside of the src=" ". How do I fix this and is there maybe a better way of doing this in general?

Answer (score 1):

Ok fixed it.

```
<%= link_to "#" do %>
     <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<%= clip.adress %>/0.jpg" height="196" width="110"> 
<% end %>
```